# Getting redirect to login page after login HTTPClient 4.5.1

Tags: java, httpclient

I am getting redirect to login page, after I logged in into the application.

Code:

```
   public class Code {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
        String stringResponse = null;
        String LOGIN_URL_INTIAL = "http://localhost:15280/****/login";
         String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:15280";
       String LOGIN_URL = BASE_URL + "/api/dologin";

    String USERNAME = "****";
    String PASSWORD = "*****";
    String cookieString = "";
    String cookie = null;
    BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

     CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)

      .build();

    //CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    // CloseableHttpClient httpclient1 = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(LOGIN_URL_INTIAL);
        CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        try {
            HttpEntity entity = response1.getEntity();

            System.out.println("Login form get: " + response1.getStatusLine());
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);

            System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");
            List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None >>>>>>");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("Intially---> " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            response1.close();
        }

        HttpUriRequest login = RequestBuilder.post().setUri(new URI(LOGIN_URL)).addParameter("j_username", USERNAME)
                .addParameter("j_password", PASSWORD).build();
        CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(login);
        try {
            HttpEntity entity = response2.getEntity();

            System.out.println("Login form get: " + response2.getStatusLine());
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);

            System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
            List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                    System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString().split("value:")[1].split("]")[0]);
                    cookieString = cookies.get(i).toString().split("value:")[1].split("]")[0];
                    System.out.println("Cookies:" + cookieString + "\n");
                    cookie = cookieString;
                }
            }
            HttpUriRequest requestDashborad = RequestBuilder.get()
                    .setUri("http://localhost:15280/****/secure/dashboard").setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie)
                    .setHeader("Accept", "*/*").setHeader("Accept-Encoding:", "gzip, deflate, br")
                    .setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8")
                    .setHeader("User-Agent",
                            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3153.0 Safari/537.36")
                    .build();
            CloseableHttpResponse requestDashboradResponse = httpclient.execute(requestDashborad);

            HttpEntity entity1 = requestDashboradResponse.getEntity();

            // Read the contents of an entity and return it as a String.
            String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity1);
            stringResponse = content;

            String q = "SELECT * FROM ds_movieSearch&maxRows=5";
            HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.get()
                    .setUri("http://localhost:15280/****/soap/v1/****/select?query="
                            + URLEncoder.encode(q, "UTF-8"))
                    .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json").build();

            CloseableHttpResponse response3 = httpclient.execute(request);
            System.out.println("dasd--->" + response3);
            // stringResponse= response3;
        } finally {
            response2.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
 }
```

}

Once I getting login into the application. I am getting status as 302. After that I try to access dashboard page it redirects me to login page.

I think somehow the cookie is getting reset to default. Can I know how can I maintain the httpCclient session?

Answer (score 0):

Status 302 is `SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY`. It means that the server is redirecting the client to a new URL. If you do not get that new URL, it is likely that the login process will not be completed server side, and the server could create a new (still not loged in) session on next request.

You **must** pay attention to the *location* header of the response having a 302 status.

Comment: @serga Ballesta yes you are right. But how can I maintain the login session. It got redirected to dashboard page. When I try to access dashboard page I am getting redirected to login page.Login session got lost. Any example it will be helpful.Thanks

Comment: @bharathi: Hmm, it is common for hidden fields to be included in forms to prevent Cross Origin Request Forgery. You should process a complete login operation from a browser and control (through the Development tools of the browser) what are the exact requests.